# Metric on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and Christoffel symbol of the second kind

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

I need to prove the following identity. $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is open and $g$ is a metric field on $\Omega$. Further $\Gamma_{\,kl}^j$ denotes the Christoffel symbol of second kind. $g^{ij}$ is the inverse matrix to $g_{ij}$ and $g$ denotes the determinant.

$$
 \Gamma_{\,jl}^j = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \log \sqrt{\vert g \vert}
$$

Here is what I have so far:
$$
\Gamma^j_{\;jl} = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk} \left( \frac{\partial }{ \partial x^l} g_{kj} + \frac{\partial}{ \partial x^j} g_{kl} - \frac{\partial}{ \partial x^k} g_{jl} \right) = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk}  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x^l} g_{kj}
$$

The second and the third term cancel each other out. Now as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry) (it's about the sixth equation, after the line starting with "The contracting relations..."

$$ \frac{1}{2} g^{jk}  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x^l} g_{kj} =
\frac{1}{2g} \frac{\partial}{ \partial x^l} g = \frac{\partial}{ \partial x^l} \log \sqrt{\vert g \vert}
$$

I don't get the second last step. I suspect it has got something to do with the Laplace formula and the Cramer Rule. However i seem not to be able to figure it out, the derivation is bugging me.

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the slick method: write $\bar g_{ik}$ for the value of $g_{ik}$ at the specific $x^l = \bar x^l$ (so $\bar g_{ik}$ is constant).  Let $x^l$ be a function of $\epsilon$ that is a perturbation of $\bar x^l$, so that $x^l = \bar x^l$ at $\epsilon=0$.

Let $$h_{ij} = \bar g^{ik} g_{kj} . \tag1$$  Then $h_{ij}$ is a perturbation of the identity: $$h_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \epsilon \frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial \epsilon} + o(\epsilon).$$  Then it is easily computed that
$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial \epsilon} = \frac{\partial h_{ii}}{\partial \epsilon} + o(\epsilon)$$
Differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $\epsilon$
$$ \frac{\partial h_{ii}}{\partial\epsilon} = \bar g^{ik} \frac{\partial g_{ki}}{\partial \epsilon} $$
Also $h = \bar g^{-1} g$.  Hence
$$ \bar g^{-1} \frac{\partial g}{\partial \epsilon} = \bar g^{ik} \frac{\partial g_{ki}}{\partial \epsilon} + o(\epsilon). $$
In particular, at $\epsilon = 0$ we can remove the overlines, and we get:
$$ g^{-1} \frac{\partial g}{\partial \epsilon} = g^{ik} \frac{\partial g_{ki}}{\partial \epsilon}. $$

Next the direct way: so $$g = \sum_\pi\sigma(\pi) \prod_i g_{i\pi(i)}.$$  Here the sum is over permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  Then
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^l} = \sum_\pi \sigma(\pi) \sum_i \frac{\partial g_{i\pi(i)}}{\partial x^l} \prod_{j \ne i} g_{j\pi(j)} \\
=\sum_{ik} \frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}\sum_{\pi:\pi(i)=k} \prod_{j\ne i}\sigma(\pi) g_{j\pi(j)} \\
=\sum_{ik} \frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l} g \ g^{ki}. $$

Comment: Hello Stephen, thanks for your answer! I'm still not sure whether I completely understood your direct solution. In order for it to work I would need to move the $g g^{ki}$ in the last equation to the left. But it seems they depend on $x^l$ so i would not be allowed to do that. In other words: what is the derivation acting on?

Comment: When I write $\frac{\partial A}{\partial b} c$, I mean $\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial b}\right) c$.

Comment: $\sum_{\pi:\pi(i)=k} \prod_{j\ne i}\sigma(\pi) g_{j\pi(j)}$ is the formula for the transpose of the adjoint matrix - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix - and hence it is $g g^{ki}$.

Comment: I rewrote the slick proof using a more easy to understand notation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620771/differentiating-the-determinant-of-the-jacobian-of-a-diffeomorphism-dont-under/620788#620788

Comment: I have one more question: Is it trivial to state that this equation is invariant under diffeomorphisms i.e.

$$
 \Gamma_{\,jl}^j[\phi] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \log \sqrt{\vert g[\phi] \vert}
$$

where $\phi \in$ Diff$(\Omega)$? If not, how would I go about proving that? My suspicion is that since when I write down the def. of the CS in terms of $g_ij$ two terms cancel out due to the symmetry and I'm left with one, so i can just state it holds for diffeomorphisms. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I would say that the argument works in any coordinate system.  So it must be invariant under a diffeomorphism.  But the question might be asking you to prove it directly, in which case I think you need to get out the formula for how the Christoffel symbol changes, and then work it out bit by bit.  In particular, I think $g[\phi]$ will become $g \sqrt{\det(\partial \phi_i/\partial x_j)}$, or something similar, which is not so trivial.