# Differentiating the determinant of the Jacobian of a diffeomorphism (don't understand a proof)

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, determinant

For each $t$, let $A_t:\Omega_0 \to \Omega_t$ be a bi-Lipschitz map between open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The map is also invertible.  It satisfies
$$\frac{d}{dt}A_t(y) = w(A_t(y),t)$$
where $w$ is a given vector field.

Let $J_{A_t}$ denote the Jacobian matrix of $A_t$. This matrix is also given to be Lipschitz in time.

How do I show that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\text{det}J_{A_t}(y) = \nabla \cdot w(A_t(y))\text{det}J_{A_t}(y)?$$

Apparently this equation holds becausse of the Lipschitz property of the matrix $J_{A_t}$. But I don't see why it holds.

(From the paper http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bonito/Papers/2012_BonitoKyzaNochetto_Stab.pdf. See page 5).

Answer (score 4):

You need the formula
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \det(G(t)) = \det(G(t)) \text{trace}[G(t)^{-1} G'(t)] .$$

Let's prove it for $t = t_0$.  Let $H(t) = G(t_0)^{-1} G(t)$.  Then $H'(t) = G(t_0)^{-1} G'(t)$.  Since $H(t_0) = I$, it is relatively straightforward to show 
$$ \frac d{dt} \det(H(t))\big|_{t = t_0} = \text{trace}(H'(t_0)) .\tag1$$
Now substitute for $H(t)$, and the formula drops out for $t = t_0$.

Since $J_{A_t}$ is Lipschitz, it is differentiable almost everywhere (by Rademacher's Theorem), and I think this should be enough to make the whole proof work.

To see $(1)$, start with $H(t) = I + (t-t_0) H'(t_0) + o(t-t_0)$.  Then if you write out the formula for the determinant, you get $\det(H(t)) = 1 + (t-t_0)\text{trace}(H'(t_0)) + o(t-t_0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a mistake in your second displayed equation by any chance?

Comment: I'm not seeing a mistake.

Comment: I added a proof.  Do you see a mistake?

Comment: Thanks for expanding, let me take some time to work through it.

Comment: You also need to take the $\nabla$ of both sides of $\frac{d}{dt}A_t(y) = w(A_t(y),t)$ to get an equation for $J_{A_t}$.  It is relatively straightforward, but a fiddly calculation.

Comment: Let's drop writing the explicit dependence on $t$, and write it out using coordinates:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} A_i(y) = w_i(A(y)) $$
So
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial A_i(y)}{\partial y_j} = \frac{\partial A_k(y)}{\partial y_j} \nabla_k w_i (A(y)) $$
or
$$ \frac{d}{dt} J_A = J_A \cdot \nabla w(A) .$$

Comment: Note $\nabla_k w(A(y))$ means differentiate $w$ with respect to its $k$th input value, and then substitute $A(y)$ for the inputs.