# Christoffel symbols proof

Tags: differential-geometry

How do I proove this? I think it's something related to "index gymnastics"...
$$\Gamma^i{}_{ki}=\frac{1}{2} g^{im}\partial_k g_{im}=\frac{1}{2g} \partial_k g =\partial_k \ln \sqrt{|g|} $$
Here's where I get stuck:
$$\Gamma^i_{.ki}=g^{im}\Gamma_{mki}=\frac{1}{2}g^{im}(\partial_i g_{mk}+\partial_k g_{mi}-\partial_m g_{ki})$$

Comment: If I recall correctly the second formula is exactly the definition of the Christoffel symbols right?

Comment: Yes... I don't know how they got the first formula

Comment: What do you mean you get stuck on the definition of the symbols?

Comment: You're one step away. The first and third terms in the last step of your work cancel (the metric tensor is symmetric, and the sums implied by the Einstein summation notation are hence the same).

Comment: I know that the metric tensor is symmetric.. but $\partial_i g_{mk}=\partial_m g_{ik}$ ?

Comment: I know $g_{ab}=g_{ba}$ :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619853/metric-on-an-open-subset-of-mathbbrd-and-christoffel-symbol-of-the-second/619922#619922

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with your work:
$$\Gamma^i_{\phantom{i}ki}=g^{im}\Gamma_{mki}=\frac{1}{2}g^{im}(\partial_i g_{mk}+\partial_k g_{mi}-\partial_m g_{ki}).$$
Notice that
\begin{align*}
g^{im}\partial_i g_{mk} & = g^{im} \partial_i g_{km} \tag{symmetry of $g$} \\
 & = g^{mi} \partial_m g_{ki} \tag{relabeling dummy indices} \\
 & = g^{im} \partial_m g_{ki}. \tag{symmetry of $g$}
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}g^{im}(\partial_i g_{mk}+\partial_k g_{mi}-\partial_m g_{ki}) & = \frac{1}{2}g^{im}\partial_k g_{mi} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} g^{mi} \partial_k g_{mi} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2g} \partial_k g \\
 & = \partial_k \ln \sqrt{|g|}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{2} g^{mi} \partial_k g_{mi} = \frac{1}{2g} \partial_k g $ ?

Comment: Sorry for being so annoying..

Comment: I get it equal to $\frac{1}{2}g \partial_k ln(g_{mi}) $