# Proof on metric tensor identity

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the proof for this proposition: $$\frac{1}{2} g^{mi} \partial_k g_{mi} =\frac{1}{2g} \partial_k g $$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619853/metric-on-an-open-subset-of-mathbbrd-and-christoffel-symbol-of-the-second/619922#619922

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a formula for the derivative of an invertible matrix given by
$$\partial_k \det(A) = \det(A) \operatorname{Tr}(A^{-1} \partial_k A).$$
I would prefer not to prove this here, so see [this post by Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/) for a proof of this formula. In our situation, $(g_{ij})$ is an invertible matrix with $(g_{ij})^{-1} = (g^{ij})$ and $\det(g_{ij}) = g$, so the formula translates to
\begin{align*}
\partial_k g & = g \operatorname{Tr} (g^{im} \partial_k g_{mj}) \\
 & = g g^{im} \partial_k g_{mi} \\
 & = g g^{mi} \partial_k g_{mi}.
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\frac{1}{g} \partial_k g = g^{mi} \partial_k g_{mi}.$$