# Metric on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and Christoffel symbol of the second kind under diffeomorphisms

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619853/metric-on-an-open-subset-of-mathbbrd-and-christoffel-symbol-of-the-second)

I proved the following identity. $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is open and $g$ is a metric field on $\Omega$. Further $\Gamma_{\,kl}^j$ denotes the Christoffel symbol of second kind. $g^{ij}$ is the inverse matrix to $g_{ij}$ and $g$ denotes the determinant.

$$
 \Gamma_{\,jl}^j = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \log \sqrt{\vert g \vert}
$$

Now my question is:

Is it trivial to state that this equation is invariant under diffeomorphisms i.e.

$$
 \Gamma_{\,jl}^j[\phi] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \log \sqrt{\vert g[\phi] \vert}
$$

where $\phi \in$ Diff$(\Omega)$? If not, how would I go about proving that?

The Christoffel Symbols transform in a rather difficult manner, however because of two indices being the same $(j)$ two of the $g_{ij}$ terms cancel each other out when we write down the definition of the Christoffel symbol, which reduces the problem to 
$$
\frac{1}{2}g[\phi]^{jk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}g[\phi]_{jk} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \log \sqrt{\vert g[\phi] \vert} 
$$

Comment: in general changing coordinates the connection coefficient obey [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Change_of_variable ]

Comment: Hi @janmarqz. Thanks for your answer. I'm aware how the Christoffelsymbols transform. However can I not just write the Christoffelsymbol in terms of $g_{ij}$ and then apply the transformation rules for the metric tensor? And if so, isn't identity trivial to state?